# SNMP в приложении

Tags: snmp, c++, linux

Доброго времени суток!

Есть некоторая большая система, которая крутится на linux ( Debian Squeeze и RHEL 6 ).
Встала задача мониторинга этой системы с помощью snmp. Доки почитал, принцип работы понял.
Остался один вопрос: как это реализовать? как-то подключаться к snmpd? или самому виснуть на 161 порт и обрабатывать запросы от snmp-менеджеров?

Comment: Конечно предоставить данные с помощью snmpd, для того он и придумывался. зачем велосипеды..

Comment: Вот в том и вопрос, как к нему подцепиться :)

Comment: Были раньше cmu-snmp, ucb-snmp... Посмотрите http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net

Comment: Есть такая штука `man snmpd.conf` и куча `SEE ALSO` в ней.

Answer (score 2):

Подключиться можно установив net-snmp (man snmpget, man snmpwalk). А можно писать свои клиенты, например через net-snmp-perl.

Но тут вопрос, а сама система то умеет что-то отдавать по SNMP, или имеется ввиду просто большой линукс сервер/ферма ?

Так же рекомендовал бы посмотреть в сторону Nagios и Cacti - это по теме мониторинга систем.

Comment: Для мониторинга используется zabbix. Вопрос был решен уже написанием snmp-субагента. Который и отдает по snmp данные с нашего приложения.